# Make the pictures in the explore-cities view clickable

Tags: feature-request, jobs, careers-city-pages

I really like the new careers city-pages, e.g. [Vancouver city page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/explore/vancouver?f=h).

One thing I find really counter-intuitive, though, is that I can't click on the pictures and get to the companies to which they belong.

It's even stranger that they get grayed out once you hover over anything so you always have to scroll on the edges of the screen.

Comment: It would be a nice if somebody with more rep could add a city-pages related tag.

Answer (score 4):

This was an interesting problem for us, and I realize that what we have right now for the photos isn't the best solution. Part of the reason that we came to the solution we have is that those photos are coming from Foursquare's API - it's not our own content. Making them clickable to our own content is a TOS gray area.

At the same time, we were trying really hard to keep the impact of the photos without making it unclear what was clickable or not. Down the line we do want to make everything on city pages interactive so the interaction will be much clearer and nothing will be grayed out.

Comment: Would it be possible to layer the click events so it doesn't interfere with the iframe but still allows for a SE click location?

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. Are the pictures in the company profiles also from Foursquare?

Comment: @bamboon The ones in the company profiles aren't from Foursquare - it's just the ones that are standalone photo tiles on the feed. We originally used the company profile assets, but it didn't have the right overall feel as it does with casual photos from 4SQ.

Comment: @TravisJ I'm not sure what you mean - could you clarify?

Comment: @JonChan - Sorry, I misunderstood and thought the photos were on a map. Please disregard that :)